# Finding the length of a chord with an arc length

Tags: geometry

Given a circle with diameter $d$, is there a way to find the length of the chord f that cuts off an arc of length $l$?
[image]

I am trying to understand the relationships between chords and arcs etc, and this concept came up - is there a general formula for it?

(And before I get shut down for this being a homework question, it is not. The concept came up in independent study.)

Answer (score 3):

The angle of the corresponding circular sector is $\frac{2l}{d}$. If you trace a line from the center through the midpoint of the chord and two more lines from the center to the chord's endpoints, you will have two right triangles. It follows from basic trigonometry that:
$$ \frac{f}{2} = \frac{d}{2} \sin\left(\frac{l}{d}\right)  $$
and therefore
$$ f = d \sin\left(\frac{l}{d}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The length of an arc of a circle is $l=r\theta$, where $r=d/2$ is the radius and $\theta$ is the central angle (in radians) subtended by the arc. So from the known arc length and radius (or diameter), you can find the angle.

Then drawing the radii to the endpoints of the chord (and the arc) gives us an isosceles triangle with the angle of $\theta$ at the vertex at the center of the circle. Drop the height/median from this vertex at the center to cut this triangle into two right triangles, and use trigonometry to find the desired length of the base. You should see that $\displaystyle \sin(\theta/2)=\frac{f/2}{r}$, from which you can find $f$.